# Copy 3 sheets' numerical values to 4th sheet

Tags: ms-office, excel-formula, excel-2007, openoffice.org

I have 4 sheets, sheet1,sheet2,sheet3,sheet4 in an excel file. All sheets are exactly same and have some cells with numeric values and others ar eeither blank or have text value.

I want the 4th sheet to have numerical values which are sum of the first 3 sheets.
Is there any general forumula which I can apply to each cell to accomplish this ?

Comment: in excel you can use [formulas with 3D references](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-a-3-d-reference-to-the-same-cell-range-on-multiple-worksheets-HP010102346.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

What version of excel are you using? This can effect the maximum number of cells on a sheet.

In excel 2007 or later, the maximum number of rows is 1048576. Using this to set the range and the SUM function you will capture every numerical value on sheets 1-3 by entering the following formula on sheet 4:

```
=SUM(Sheet1! 1:1048576, Sheet2! 1:1048576, Sheet3! 1:1048576)
```

For pre 2007 versions (and 2007 working in compatibility mode) the maximum is 65536.